# What can I use to attach a strap to the tripod socket on my camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod-socket, camera-straps

Just bought a new strap which I'm very happy with then saw the fancy-schmancy [slings](http://www.lu.ma/loop) that attach to the tripod-screw mount under the camera.

Is there a threaded bolt with a loop or two to allow me to attach one or both ends of my new strap to the tripod bolt? Something [like this](http://customslr.com/products/c-loop) but perhaps cheaper and available in the UK?

I have a Nikon D5000.

Comment: FWIW, the tripod thread is standardized, so the camera model shouldn't matter much if at all.

Comment: I thought it would be but confused by the fact both 3/8" and 1/4" threads are available on things that fit it?

Comment: http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5000_en.pdf page 228. It's definitely a ¼" socket.

Comment: Cool, many thanks. It *shouldn't* be too hard to find a suitable piece of ironmongery now ;)

Comment: from wikipedia: "The historic standard threading for the bolt that attaches the camera to the tripod is 1/4"-20tpi (threads per inch) British Standard Whitworth (Whitworth or BSW) for smaller cameras or 3/8"-16tpi BSW for larger cameras and pan/tilt heads."

Comment: I found a great article on lifehacker which I think I'm going to go with: http://abella.net/?page_id=140

Comment: @5arx I'd be worried about that plastic buckle - those things aren't particularly strong, and they make it really easy for a thief to grab your camera.

Comment: @Evan Krall - I agree. I think I'm just going to use a one piece strap. In any case I don't see the need for those quick-release things in this scenario - once the strap/sling is on it'll stay on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a year on, I found the [Opteka NS-7](http://amzn.to/zRTk5E) on Amazon UK. I will post my findings once it arrives ...

UPDATE:

The strap is rubbish, but the tripod mount is perfect. Swivels nicely and costs about a quarter of what the C-Loop does. Recommended!

Answer (score 2):

I have improvised my own asymmetric strap using a camera bag strap, [this Manfrotto spigot](http://www.manfrotto.co.uk/product/8373.56.48467.0.0/118/_/Short_16mm_Spigot_with_14%27_and_38%27_screw) and [a carabiner like this](http://www.wickes.co.uk/steel-carbine-hook/invt/159411/). Not pretty, but it works and is relatively cheap.

Comment: Aha - the word I'm looking for is `spigot`! Many thanks, will investigate further.

Comment: About the spigot - you should be careful not to unscrew the thing while hanging your camera. It looks like there is no axis there allowing for free rotation of the carabine, so it ma get loose with time on your body!

Comment: Yes, you have to make sure it's good and tight. I still hold the camera while it's down by my side, but it's a lot more comfortable than having it round your neck.

Comment: @ysap: Any ideas on how to fix the problem you described? Some sort of swivel between the spigot and the strap?

Comment: @Craig Walker - look at my answer to this question. Also, if you can get yourself a carabine with the swivel functionality, you have an equivalent solution.

Comment: @ElindilTheTall - any chance you could post a photo of your solution in action ...?

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @ElindilTheTall - still waiting for that photo ;-)

Comment: If you can work out a way for me to take a photo _of_ my camera, _with_ my camera, it'll be up in moments!

Comment: Surely you have more than one camera? How about the one on your cellphone? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to check out the [Camdapter](http://camdapter.com/home.html), which has been around a while. It functions as both a Arca/Manfrotto/etc quick release adapter and a mount for attaching your shoulder strap, in the usual way.

Comment: Looks great, struggling to find a UK supplier though ...

:(

Comment: I can't find a US supplier either. I think they're small and mostly do direct-sales. They say they'll ship anywhere in the world....

Comment: ... at a price approx. 1/3 of the cost of the bloody thing :-(

Plus I *may* get stung for duty once it arrives :-(

Answer (score 2):

A quick release plate like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009R6FJ) can do the job.

Update: While thinking about it, this does not solve the swivel problem I noted in one of the comments to ElendilTheTall, as the ring is attached, and rotates with the screw. However, it does give you a better resistance (friction) to unscrewing than his solution, if you tighten it well enough.

Comment: Note that the rings in these plates are not designed to take any weight and I have heard stories of cameras falling to ground after the ring has spread out under the weight. So if you do go for something like this make sure that it is sturdy enough.

Comment: @Dan - that's a very good point. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend products from [Luma](http://lu.ma) -- they focus on camera slings, but make a tripod mount called [PodMount](http://www.lu.ma/podmount) that you could probably attach anything you wanted to.

(Incidentally, their slings are great -- they mount only to the right-side strap mount, letting the camera fall very naturally against your hip.)

Comment: Do you know if the PodMount swivels or if its fixed to the tripod mount?

Also, it looks like it might be for compacts only?

Comment: @5arx: I've never used it so I don't know if it swivels, but it doesn't look like it. The Luma quick-release clasp that goes with their straps *does* swivel, which is maybe why that one doesn't. I don't think it's just for compacts: they make a point of saying you can mount it to lens tripod mounts, and the photo looks like it's mounted on an SLR. Besides, don't all cameras use the same thread size?

Answer (score 2):

I use a blackrapid strap and a manfrotto tripod with a quick release plate and this quick release plate screw works awesome for me. http://www.blackrapid.com/product/hardware/fr-t1/ It is only $18 dollars and I think it should be available in the UK. The build quality is top notch. There is even a little rubber ring to stop the screw from scratching things.

Comment: Does the plate screw swivel when connected to the tripod mount?

Comment: No it doesn't swivel. That mounting screw is designed to work with a strap that has a swivel.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon sell the Custom SLR C-Loop Camera Strap Mount in the UK but the price is somewhat prohibitive still:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Custom-SLR-C-Loop-Camera-Silver/dp/B004V71BJM

Comment: That's `exactly` what I need!

But the price ... You say 'prohibitive' - I say its more like 'ridiculous'.

I wonder if something similar exists in the world of metal bolts and fixings. Something like a dog-walking carabiner maybe http://bit.ly/ldv3IR ...

Answer (score 1):

A really cheap option is to get a [1/4-20 Eye Bolt](http://www.lowes.com/pd_136732-37672-881853_4294856649+4294829729_4294937087_?productId=3012388&Ns=p_product_prd_lis_ord_nbr%7C0%7C%7Cp_product_quantity_sold%7C1&pl=1&currentURL=/pl_Eye_4294856649%2b4294829729_4294937087_?Ns=p_product_prd_lis_ord_nbr%7C0%7C%7Cp_product_quantity_sold%7C1&facetInfo=Eye).  It can screw into the camera, then you connect the strap to the eye ring.

Comment: You get what you pay for  :-/

Answer (score 1):

They look cool - until the thing works loose and your camera gets dropped. What's wrong with attaching the camera strap to the camera strap fixing points ?
I believe it's 1/4" BSP - British Standard Pipe thread. 1/4-20 is pretty close. 3/8" is for medium and large format film cameras - pro kit.

Comment: I like the fact that is that the tripod-mount attached strap/sling is a lot less obtrusive and allows for easy shooting in both landscape and portrait format. In addition it makes the camera hang in a more symmetric/ergonomically better way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm own a CarrySpeed camera strap that attaches to the tripod socket on my D7000.  I like that the strap itself has a tiny pouch to carry a few extra SD cards as well.
http://www.carryspeed.com/

For a bit more money with more options there is also http://www.blackrapid.com/

Comment: I own a BlackRapid RS-7 strap. Works a treat!